# What should I do about frozen modules warning in JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

When I launch JupyterLab (with `jupyter lab`) I get the warning

```
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

1. I assume that if I'm doing debugging I should do something about this so I don't "miss breakpoints", or can I just ignore this (and even stop seeing it by setting `PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION`).
2. If I should indeed do something about this, how do I configure my virtual environment — or perhaps Jupyter? —so that  `Xfrozen_modules=off` automatically whenever I run `jupyter lab`?

Comment: @Wayne What does "without acknowledgment" mean?

Comment: @Wayne I often find the opposite. Different communities provide different insights, and suggesting that a similar post has been made elsewhere often slows or even shuts down conversation. In any case, I think you should have more trust in OP's wishes and in their ability to synthesize what they learn and make that available to both communities. (Also that explains why you take it on yourself to cross link, but not what "without acknowledgment" means.)

Comment: @Wayne Thanks, I appreciate it. I'll be sure to keep any crossposts updated as I learn from each community.

Comment: @krassowski No it was not.

Comment: Yes, it was. I answered the question there. Are you removing our comments?  (this will probably end with volunteers from Jupyter stopping to help here and focus only on answering on Discourse)

Comment: @krassowski Removing comments? No. If you believe there is something there that would qualify as an answer here, then by all means propose it, _here_.

Comment: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/what-should-i-do-about-frozen-modules-warning/21528/6